# How to force pandoc to number all ordered lists starting from one (1)?

Tags: list, markdown, pandoc

I have a Markdown document which is generated by some application. All things go correct, but there are some problems with ordered lists.

Below is minimal reproducible example of such Markdown document:

```
# Heading 1

Some text

## Heading 1.1

1. list item
1. list item

## Heading 1.2

3. list item
1. list item

## Heading 1.3

7. list item
3. list item
```

The output format really does not matter, but for PDF (produced by `pandoc list-test.md -o list.pdf`) I get the following:

[image: pdf output]

But for example ReText renders the code as expected:

[image: ReText]

Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason here is that ReText uses Python Markdown.

Comparison [using Babelmark 2](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%23+Heading+1%0A%0ASome+text%0A%0A%23%23+Heading+1.1%0A%0A1.+list+item%0A1.+list+item%0A%0A%23%23+Heading+1.2%0A%0A3.+list+item%0A1.+list+item%0A%0A%23%23+Heading+1.3%0A%0A7.+list+item%0A3.+list+item%0A) gives a clue that we need to switch Pandoc to the [`markdown_strict`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--from) mode by:

```
pandoc list-test.md -o list.pdf --from=markdown_strict
```

to get expected rendering.

Also using `markdown_phpextra` or `markdown_mmd` by:

```
pandoc list-test.md -o list.pdf --from=markdown_phpextra
pandoc list-test.md -o list.pdf --from=markdown_mmd
```

will [fix](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%23+Heading+1%0A%0ASome+text%0A%0A%23%23+Heading+1.1%0A%0A1.+list+item%0A1.+list+item%0A%0A%23%23+Heading+1.2%0A%0A3.+list+item%0A1.+list+item%0A%0A%23%23+Heading+1.3%0A%0A7.+list+item%0A3.+list+item%0A&from=markdown_mmd&to=plain&standalone=0) the issue too.